# decodeURI not working with innerHTML text

Tags: javascript, html, json, decode, decodeuricomponent

I've been trying decode text, so I can take unescape JSON encoding. But I can't get to work when the variable value is innerHTML but it works when I hardcode the same string value to the variable.

innerHTML Example (I need help with)

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="uri">C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var uri = document.getElementById("uri").innerText;
  var dec = decodeURI(uri.toString());
  var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected Result: Decoded URI: C:\Users\User\Documents\Fax

Working example with a hardcoded value

```html
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="uri">Decode</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var uri = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax";
      var dec = decodeURI(uri.toString());
      var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Actual Result: Decoded URI: C:\Users\User\Documents\Fax

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That text is not URI-encoded. In fact it's not really a URI at all; it's a Windows file path.

Comment: This was a simplified example but in my actual application "\" is converted to "\\" and each enter is converted to \r on when submitting.

Comment: Why is JSON being talked about here? I don't see any JSON being used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
var uri = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax";
```

actually sets `uri` to `C:\Users\User\Documents\Fax`. Since you are simply creating a string with the backslashes escaped.

The line:

```
var uri = document.getElementById("uri").innerText;
```

sets `uri` to `C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax` with two backslashes in each position.

If you want the string solution to behave the same, you need to escape the backslashes again when creating the string. (i.e. `var uri = "C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\Documents\\\\Fax";`)

---

To fix your first version to work as the second currently does, you can use a RegEx replacement to change `C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax` to `C:\Users\User\Documents\Fax` (or if it is possible, simply change the html element to contain `C:\Users\User\Documents\Fax`).

**RegEx solution:**

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="uri">C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var uri = document.getElementById("uri").innerText.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\");
  console.log("uri = " + uri);
  var dec = decodeURI(uri.toString());
  var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**To parse all escaped characters (`\\`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, ...):**

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="uri">C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Fax</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var uri = document.getElementById("uri").innerText;
  console.log("uri = " + uri);

  uri = JSON.parse(`"${uri}"`);
  console.log("parsed uri = " + uri);

  var dec = decodeURI(uri.toString());
  var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see what you are doing with replace although that works for "\\" usecase, decodeURI still ignores decoding \n, \r other JSON Espace characters that it adds to my strings.

Comment: @DN0300 It seems like you just want to remove all backslash escaping from the variable. In that case, `JSON.parse` should be all you need. This should work: `JSON.parse(\`"${document.getElementById("uri").innerText}"\`);` (or see full example added at end of my answer).

Comment: @DN0300 Like lakshitha said, `decodeURI` is for hex encoded strings like `"%5C%20%C3"` and not backslash escaped strings, so it doesn't do anything to your string.

Comment: Is there something similar to json.Parse I can use for innerHtml?

Answer (score 0):

**Use encoded URI to decode, if not we couldn't  see the difference.**

```html
<p id="uri">my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var uri = document.getElementById("uri").innerText;
        var dec = decodeURI(uri.toString());
        var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
```